# Ionic - display SideMenu while moving between states

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm currently starting my project with [Ionic Starter SideMenu](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-sidemenu). In my app, I want to move between states while showing the SideMenu. But the state change will not be driven by a menu click, rather a condition in the main controller. This is an example of a state driven from the menu:

```
 .state('app.browse', {
  url: "/browse",
  views: {
   'menuContent': {
     templateUrl: "templates/browse.html"
    }
  }
 })
```

How do I declare a state which will not be clicked from the menu?

Many Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare the state in states and don't put a link to that state into the menu.html

If you want to switch to that state use "$state.go("app.browse");"

Enjoy :)

Comment: Hi @zishor, thanks for responding. But how do I declare that state as something that is not accessed from the menu? I.e. in the code example above, it references 'menuContent' because this is the linked nav-view and it is accessed from the SideMenu. Would I just omit 'views'?

Comment: If I understood you correctly you want to have states that are not listed in the side menu (please tell me if I got that wrong). 
Just go ahead and declare a new state. You will not find it listed in the side menu because you need to manually add it to the menu.html. 

You can even dynamically show menu entries. Example: only show the logout button when the user is loggedin: 

         <ion-item ng-show="isLoggedIn" ng-click="logout()" nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/sign-in">
         <i class="icon ion-log-out"></i>
          {{'logout' | translate}}
        </ion-item>

Comment: I just meant that in the code snippet above, it has 'views' and 'menuContent'. But because I would not be accessing it as a menu item, I was wondering whether I should omit the 'menuContent' declaration in the state.